# Filter out records with at least one association that doesn't meet given conditions

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

Let's say I have `posts` and `categorizations`.

`Post(id)`

`Categorization(post_id, topic_id)`

I'd like to fetch posts that don't belong to a specific topic id.

In my case I have to use an inner join when joining Post to Categorizations as i have other filters to execute.

How do I go about this?

I have tried the following:

`Post.joins(:categorizations).where("categorizations.topic_id != ?", doomed_topic_id)`

But this returns posts that still have OTHER topics. it only works with posts with just one single topic that happens to be the unwanted one.

For instance, if I have a post with 2 categories (the doomed topic_id AND another topic) this query fails and actually fetches it, instead of filtering it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
Posts.where('not exists
               (select * from categorizations
                  where post_id = posts.id and
                        topic_id = ?)', doomed_id)
```

Comment: You're a life saver Mori! Thanks a bunch